# I have to create a Binary Expression tree that stores the expression 2 + 4 - 3 in java

Tags: java, binary-tree, expression-trees

I am new to trees and am having issues with the code attached below, when I print out the tree, my arithmetic symbols are displaying as 0's.

Could anyone shed some light on this piece of code? Thanks!

**Here is my node class:**

```
class Node
{ 

    Node left; 
    Node right; 
    int data;
    char data1;

    Node(int newData) 
    { 
        left = null; 
        right = null; 
        data = newData; 
    }
    Node(char newData) 
    { 
        left = null; 
        right = null; 
        data1 = newData; 
    }
}
```

**Here is my Test class:**

```
public class Ex23d

    {
    public static void main(String[] args){

    Node root = new Node('+');
        root.left = new Node(2);
        root.right = new Node('-');
        Node r2 = root.right;

        r2.left = new Node(4);
        r2.right = new Node(3); 

        printTree(root);
    }
    public static void printTree() 
    { 
        printTree(); 
        System.out.println(); 
    }
    public static void printTree(Node node) 
    { 
        if (node == null) return;

        printTree(node.left); 
        System.out.print(node.data + "  "); 
        printTree(node.right); 
    }
}
```

My output should look like below.

**Output:**

```
2  0  4  0  3
```

Comment: you're not using "node.data1" which is the property that holds the characters.

Comment: Note that we normally evaluate from left to right for equal ranged operators like (+,-) or (*,/). So the evaluation order is (2+4)-3. In Trees, we collapse the leaves first, so the root would be - then. But I'm not deep in trees, maybe there is an alternativ way of solving such a tree, where your approach is fine.

Answer (score 2):

you are storing`+/-` in `data1` but while printing you are always calling `data` which is by default 0. You can check `data1` if `null`, based on that you can print either `data` or `data1`

Answer (score 1):

you're not using `".data1"` which is the property that holds the characters.

try this:

```
public static void printTree(Node node) 
{ 
    if (node == null) return;
    printTree(node.left); 
    if(node.data == 0){
       System.out.print(node.data1 + "  "); 
    }else{
       System.out.print(node.data + "  "); 
    }
    printTree(node.right); 
}
```